# javascript to select dropdownlist automatically based on another dropdown

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am having 2 dropdown lists on my page if i select an item the same selected item should be displayed in another drop down list. Can any one give me a `javascript` for this i need `Javascript` not `Jquery`

Comment: What code do you already have? Besides, jQuery _is_ JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>



  <script type="text/javascript">
function MyApp(sender){
    var lbMatch = false;
    var loDDL2 = document.getElementById('DropDownList1');
    for(var i=0; i< loDDL2.length-1; i++){
        lbMatch = sender.value==loDDL2.options[i].value;       
        lsSelected = lbMatch ? "<=SELECTED" : "";
        if(lbMatch)
            loDDL2.selectedIndex = sender.selectedIndex;
    }
}
        </script>
```

In page load event add this

```
  ddl1.Attributes.Add("OnChange", "MyApp(this)");
```

Comment: Thanks Muhammad Akhtar and Dorababu

Answer (score 1):

You can attach an onchange event on your dropdown.
Then whenever your selected Index changes, it will fire and call the supplied update method.
For example:

### HTML

```
<asp:DropDownList id="FirstDropdown" onChange="javascript:update();" ...>
```

### JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function update ( ) {        
   document.getElementById('<%= SecondDropdown.ClientID %>').value =
   document.getElementById('<%= FirstDropdown.ClientID %>' ).value;        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a very simple implementation of what you are describing:

given the html:

```
<select id="select1">
  <option value="foo">foo</option>
  <option value="bar">bar</option>
</select>
<select id="select2">
  <option value="foo">foo</option>
  <option value="bar">bar</option>
</select>
```

and this javascript:

```
document.getElementById('select1').onchange = function(e) {
  var index = this.selectedIndex;
  document.getElementById('select2').options[index].selected = true;
}
```

you can achieve what you want.  note the indexes should be exactly the same in both select boxes (as in the options should be in the same order)