# select value of one dropdown based on another dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 dropdown lists-

> 1) First dropdown list for client ID
>
> 2) Second dropdown list for client name

What I want is when user selects client id then in the another dropdown client name should be selected who having that selected id.
Second Thing I want that If user selects client name then in the client id dropdown that client's client id should be selected.
What I have done so far-

```
<select class="form-control" id="client_id">
    <?php
         while($c_id=mysql_fetch_array($client_id))
           {
              echo "<option>".$c_id['ID']."</option>"; 
           }
     ?>
 </select>

 <select class="form-control" id="client_name">
     <?php
         while($c_name=mysql_fetch_array($client_name))
            {
                echo "<option value='".$c_name['ID']."'>".$c_name['display_name']."</option>";
            }
      ?>
 </select>
```

Jquery -

```
$('#client_id').change(function(){
    //Client name should be select here base on selected id
}); 

$('#client_name').change(function(){
    //Client id should be select here base on selected client name
});
```

Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select an option in a dropdown list based on a selection in another dropdown list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965597/how-to-select-an-option-in-a-dropdown-list-based-on-a-selection-in-another-dropd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the code below:

```
$(function() {
    $('#client_id').change(function(){
        id = $( "#client_id option:selected" ).text();
        $("#client_name > option").each(function() {
            name = this.text;
            idFromName = name.replace(/(^\d+)(.+$)/i,'$1');
            if (id == idFromName){
                $('#client_name').val(name);
            }
                });
    });

    $('#client_name').change(function(){
        name = $( "#client_name option:selected" ).text();
        idFromName = name.replace(/(^\d+)(.+$)/i,'$1');
        $("#client_id > option").each(function() {
            id = this.text;
            if (id == idFromName){
                $('#client_id').val(idFromName);
            }
                });
    });
});
```

In the code above, when the `clinet_id` dropdown is changed, the id of the selected option is kept in the `id` variable. Then it loops through the options of the other dropdown (`client_name`) and for every option the option's text is kept in the variable `name`. Then using regular expression (using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965597/how-to-select-an-option-in-a-dropdown-list-based-on-a-selection-in-another-dropd)) only the id from the text is kept in the `idFromName` variable. If the `id` and the `idFromName` are equal it changes the `client_name` dropdown to the current selection. With the same logic, this also happens when the `client_name` dropdown is changed.

**You can test it in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a8je1t49/1/).**

Sources:

- [How to select an option in a dropdown list based on a selection in another dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965597/how-to-select-an-option-in-a-dropdown-list-based-on-a-selection-in-another-dropd)
- [Get the first Int(s) in a string with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609574/get-the-first-ints-in-a-string-with-javascript)
- [Iterate through <select> options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950152/iterate-through-select-options)
- [Set select option 'selected', by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343566/set-select-option-selected-by-value)
- http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/

**UPDATE**

Here is a full working example:

```
<select id="client_id">
<option>125</option>
<option>53</option>
<option>7</option>
</select>

<select id="client_name">
<option>125>asd</option>
<option>53>rty</option>
<option>7>ruu</option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#client_id').change(function(){
        id = $( "#client_id option:selected" ).text();
        $("#client_name > option").each(function() {
            name = this.text;
            idFromName = name.replace(/(^\d+)(.+$)/i,'$1');
            if (id == idFromName){
                $('#client_name').val(name);
            }
                });
    });

    $('#client_name').change(function(){
        name = $( "#client_name option:selected" ).text();
        idFromName = name.replace(/(^\d+)(.+$)/i,'$1');
        $("#client_id > option").each(function() {
            id = this.text;
            if (id == idFromName){
                $('#client_id').val(idFromName);
            }
                });
    });
});
</script>
```

Copy and paste this and make your adjustments for your ids and names.

Comment: I edited it. Doesn't it work now either? Check the JSFiddle provided.

Comment: I just copy, paste your code still it's not working.

Comment: See my update. I put this code in a file and when I test it it works. I can't understand why it doesn't work for you. Does the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a8je1t49/1) work?